# Passing arguments collected in one PHP file to be sent as email in another php

Tags: php, forms

I'm collecting an argument from a signup URL using '?' like this,

```
.../signup.php?id=6489
```

now i'm collecting this 'id' in my php in this way,

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // echo $id;
?>
```

Now i want to use this $id in another PHP file - code_exec.php where there is a mail() function which emails this and other parameters collected from a form. Now the parameters collected from the Form work great and they all show properly in the email. However this ID variable does not. I have included the signup.php in code_exec.php using this,

```
include 'signup.php';
```

and yet it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds like, you go to `signup.php?id=6489`, fill out a form which submits to `code_exec.php` and you want to get the ID in `code_exec.php`.

If that is the case, you can include a hidden form field in the signup page with that ID.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
```

and that will get submitted with the form just like all of the other fields. Make sure to sanitize your inputs!

Comment: On your server side, make sure you're accepting only what you want the user to enter. You're not querying the db so you don't have to worry about injections but you might have issues with quotes and stuff. And what happens if I enter a word into that instead of a number?

Comment: Ah yes! I do have a basic validation javascript but I intend to make it more sophisticated...

Comment: FYI I know you're new here and all, but if one of these answers suits your needs, you should "accept" it. It's also nice to upvote helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Without showing what's in signup.php and how you're using that $id value, we can't help. But the obvious one: If the signup.php stuff is working inside a function, then you're subject to PHP's scoping rules and will have to make `$id` a global, eg.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

function email() {
   global $id;
   blah blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// foo.php
$id = '12345';
include 'bar.php';

// bar.php
echo $id;
```

Will output 12345. Any variables that exist in scope of the include/require call will be available in the included file.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input value to your form and assign it the passed id value, something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
```